# a cross-browser solution for limiting horizontal scroll width only with CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a css only cross-browser solution for this, but i couldnt manage it without any js

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/604317/test/index.html

do you guys have any other suggestions?

Comment: Your question is woefully short on details, plus you should post your code here. If the page you link to changes or goes away, this question loses all value.

Comment: Which part is not consistent throughout all browsers? What's is the problem area?

Comment: What are you asking? Are you asking about how to prevent your text from shrinking with the window below a certain point? b/c for that you should use `min-width`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what you're asking.

You can use multiple backgrounds in most modern browser for example:

```
#container{
    background: transparent url('img') repeat-x top left, 
    background: transparent url('img') repeat-x bottom left,
    background: transparent url('img') repeat-y top right,
    background: transparent url('img') repeat-y top left
}
```

[mozilla link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multiple_backgrounds)

or you could use an old technique of nested divs with different backgrounds:

```
<div class="top_bg">
    <div class="bottom_bg">
        <div class="right_bg">
            <div class="left_bg">
                <p>lorem</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.top_bg{
    background: transparent url('img') repeat-x top left;
    padding: 10px 0 0;
}
.bottom_bg{
    background: transparent url('img') repeat-x bottom left;
    padding: 0 0 10px;
}
.right_bg{
    background: transparent url('img') repeat-y top right;
}
.left_bg{
    background: transparent url('img') repeat-y top left;
}
```

notice the padding to top and bottom.

back before all this border-radius stuff we would have to use this technique to set rounded corner images to containers to make it fluid with content. Now things are a lot easier.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jBgLx/)